# What is the proper way to load new content into a kendo window?

Tags: windows, modal-dialog, kendo-ui

I have a kendo window that has a form inside it. The form has input elements with a record's data populated within it. The user may close the window and select a different record to view. When the user does this, I need to show the kendo window again with the same form but with different record data. Here's what I'm currently doing

```
    if (!$("#winContainer").data("kendoWindow")) {
        $("#winContainer").kendoWindow({
            modal: true,
            width: "969px",
            height: "646px",
            title: "View Record",
            content: "record.jsp"
        });
    } else {
        $("#winContainer").data("kendoWindow").refresh({url: 'record.jsp'});
    }

    $("#winContainer").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```

The form is contained within record.jsp, and I populate it with JSON data that I previously received from server (via JavaScript referenced in record.jsp). I need to ensure that the window does not show until the new record data is populated in the form. Is this the correct way to do this or is there some better way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of creating a new window each time or refreshing its content, I do recommend:

1. Create a window,
2. Each the user selects a new record, bind the new data to the window and then open it.

This way you only need to load the page once.

You might also consider having the page `record.jsp` defined as a Kendo UI template in your original page.

**Example:**

Given the following user selectable records:

```
var data = [
    { text1: "text1.1", text2: "text1.2" },
    { text1: "text2.1", text2: "text2.2" },
    { text1: "text3.1", text2: "text3.2" },
    { text1: "text4.1", text2: "text4.2" }
];
```

And a form defined as a template with the following HTML:

```
<script id="record-jsp" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <p>This is your form with some sample data</p>
        <label>text1: <input type="text" data-bind="value: text1"></label>
        <label>text2: <input type="text" data-bind="value: text2"></label>
    </div>
</script>
```

Our JavaScript would be something like:

```
// Window initialization
var kendoWindow = $("<div id='window'/>").kendoWindow({
    title    : "Record",
    resizable: false,
    modal    : true,
    viewable : false,
    content  : {
        template: $("#record-jsp").html()
    }
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

Bind data to the window and opening it:

```
function openForm(record) {
    kendo.bind(kendoWindow.element, record);
    kendoWindow.open().center();
}
```

And finally invoking the function with the data.

```
openForm(data[0]);
```

You can see it running on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/S7K4r/)

**NOTE:** If you still prefer using the external page, just need to change `template: $("#record-jsp").html()` by: `url: "record.jsp"`

Comment: Thank you for showing me this approach. It works when binding complex objects. Using this approach will require a decent number of changes to my application, but it's definitely worth it. I have to release the application very soon, so it will have to be a next phase change. Thanks again.

Comment: So for this release if you prefer to prepare the final page content in record.jsp you can always add some sort of parameter that would allow the servlet deciding what to render. I mean, something like `record.jsp?arg1=xyz&arg2=yzx&arg3=zxy`.

Comment: Thanks for giving me another alternative for the short term and for the quick response. I worked a little more on my original approach and think it will be fine for the initial release. But your approach is definitely better, and I'll get that in the next release. I just wish I (asked) knew about your approach earlier in my development.

Comment: @OnaBai: I am using something similar like this in a website I'm working on, but I'm using another syntax for the template (using #:Property# notation). The problem is that I get an uncaught ReferenceError ("Property is not defined") when the kendoWindow is created (which is reasonable as the window isn't bound to any dataItem at that time). Do you have any idea on how to avoid this?

Comment: anyone noticed that scrolling the window doesnt seem to work as expected?

Comment: @OnaBai How to use this approach to MVC html page which is located in some other folder(mainly its not a view i.e not a viewresult)? Any Ideas?