# Kendoui: Whats the best way to build simple remote form

Tags: kendo-ui

Ive just started learning Kendoui and have got to grips with grids etc.

However i want to create a details form page for the items in the grid so they can be updated. Ive used the popup feature in Kendoui grid which is fine but i really need it on a separate page because of the size of the form.

The problem is that there are no example on their website of a simple form that is binded a remote datasource.

I was wondering if someone could tell me what the best approach to use and maybe give me a simple example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are right!, there is no standard way of creating a custom popup editor but we should recognize that there is not because being custom, there is no easy (possible?) way of doing it since each of us will request a different thing.

**BUT** that doesn't mean that you cannot (pretty easily) do it.

These are, basically (as far as I can see), the steps to follow:

1. Define your own way of "poping-up" that window containing your complex form. You can do it by selecting a row and then click a custom [toolbar](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#toolbar-array) button.
2. Get the data of the [selected row](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#select),
3. Bind the data to you popup window using [kendo.bind](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#bind)
4. When [closing this window](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#close) since the data is bound to the datagrid, the [DataSource.transport.update](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportupdate-objectstringfunction) is invoked and your data in the server is updated.

You might also be interested on taking a look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14505323/1802671) that shows how to bind data to a window including reference to an example in JSFiddle.

This might seem harder than what it actually is but if you are familiar with the different KendoUI widgets, it is actually pretty easy.

Comment: Just fyi, the question was about creating a regular form on a seperate page instead of using a popup editor

Comment: @dan, OP mentions several times _different page_  as you perfectly say but also says _I've used the popup feature in Kendoui grid which is fine_. So, it seems that the only limitation about the popup is actually that OP cannot control popup layout. Here I provide the knobs on defining the popup window (OP initial idea) but with all the freedom for using whichever layout the OP wants. I agree it is not a separate page but I think that meets his/her expectations.

Comment: OnaBia, I wasn't trying to criticize your answer, it is still valuable info, just that it seemed to want to know how to build a seperate form.  This same question was asked several times in the KendoUI site forums and I also wanted to know this when I started with Kendo, it actually to me a lot of time to figure out how to make a stand alone form with the kendo datasource so I thought I would post an example.  One of the main problems I had which after hours of searching I found was that the datasource expects an array and not a single entity.

Comment: @dan, and I'm not trying to criticize your comment :-D It's just saying that it's easier and personally I think that a better user experience, do not open pages but using a Kendo UI window (as the default popup). It is easier to program and nicer for the user. And yes, probably I might have posted an example but it would have been a pretty long answer. If the OP still wants to know how to exactly do it, then I would edit the anser and add it but if it is useless for him/her then there is no point on wasting time and space.

Comment: @OnaBia, Speaking of editor popups if you don't mind I am having a problem with validation tooltip positioning take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537379/kendoui-validation-tooltip-in-custom-popup-editor-not-positioning-correctly.  If you have any ideas it would be greatly appriciated, the jsfiddle is an example straight from kendo just with validation added and the tooltip is not positioning correctly.

Comment: I've already seen it and the only idea is actually playing with CSS styles but that moves the tooltip but doesn't position correctly the arrow, that's why I didn't anser to it: sorry! I'll give another thought on it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I appreciate it. I am still hacking away at it looking at the html debugger for the classes it uses ect and trying to figure out how to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an app example I made that demonstrates a grid view to a detail page, it uses Angular for navigation.  The backend db is Wakanda a custom nosql db but you can use any datasource or local data.  Let me know if this helps or you need any further explanation of the project.  The MVVM is a little more updated with code comments for the functions.

First example is [with MVVM](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/grid/mvvm-crud-validation-multiple-kendoui-widgets-spa-angular-using-wakanda-as-db.aspx)

Next example same project but [not using MVVM](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/grid/crud-datasource-validation-multiple-kendoui-widgets-spa-angular-using-wakanda-as-db.aspx) just manually set input values from datasource using jquery

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24tNSnr4aUk&feature=youtu.be) of what it looks like