# when refreshed with new options, kendo popup window in iframe mode does not fetch the new url

Tags: kendo-ui

EDIT: I have abandoned the conditional structure and just create the window fresh each time. That works. Still wondering whether refresh() works with urls though.

I have a conditional structure that resembles this one:

[What is the proper way to load new content into a kendo window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505160/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-new-content-into-a-kendo-window)

If the kendo window already exists, refresh() the window rather than create it anew.

The difference is, I'm using an iframe with url.

The problem: I set a different query string with setOptions before invoking refresh(), but the *original* url is being requested from the server again.

```
   if (!kwindow) {
        kwindow =  $("#messagewindow").kendoWindow({ 
        iframe: true,
        width: "400px",
        height: "600px",               
        title: "original title", 
        content: "foo.htm?id=1",
        type: "GET"
    }).data("kendoWindow");    

  }else {

     kwindow.setOptions({
        iframe: true,
        type: "GET",
        title: aDifferentTitle,                    
        url : "foo.htm?id=2" 
     });
     kwindow.refresh(); 

  }
   kwindow.open();
```

I know the the **setOptions** method is passing the options to the kendo window because the titlebar of the window correctly shows *aDifferentTitle*.  However, looking at the network traffic monitor, the url requested from the server is `foo.htm?id=1` but it should be `foo.htm?id=2`.

I cannot see what is wrong with my code and would be grateful if someone could point out the error to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh from different URL you need to pass this through an option object to the **refresh** method (you do not need to use setOptions). Here is snippet from the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#refresh):

```
var windowObject = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
windowObject.refresh("/feedbackForm");

windowObject.refresh({
    url: "/feedbackForm"        
});
```

Comment: thanks, but that does not work; the URL is not refreshed when a configuration object with the new url is passed to the `refresh()` method instead of using `setOptions()`.

Comment: Is the following a valid configuration object to pass to the refresh() method? The title does not change when I pass it:`{url:"http://www.postgres.com",title:"PostgreSQL"}` It is not clear (at least not to me) which properties are to be set with setOptions() and which can be set using the configuration object passed as a single argument.

Comment: Put the issue into a jsbin so we can see what you mean.

Comment: This change in the jsbin example you created above, passing an options object rather than a URL string to refresh() method:  `window.data("kendoWindow").refresh({url:"http://www.kendoui.com",title:"kendo test title"});`  -- I assume `title` is invalid here and must be set with the title() method instead?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you were looking for was

kwindow.options.content.url = url;

Then the refresh icon / methods will work on the new url

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it seems to work in an MVC project:

```
    window.setOptions({
        title: "New Title"
     });

    window.refresh({
        url: "/ControllerName/Action"
    });

    window.open();
```