# Jquery : How to access div tag under script in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below html. I am trying to access the div tag warningMessage under scripts.

```
<script id="notePopup" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <p class="notePopupMessage">Please enter a note:</p>
    <input class="textNote k-textbox" type="text" maxlength="512" />
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="add k-button">Add</button>
        <button class="cancel k-button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <div id = "warningMessage" style="visibility: hidden" >
    <p id="warningMsg" > Status change action note would not be saved until Save button is selected. </p>
    <div>
</script>
```

I tried to access div id warningMessage and set the visibility to not hidden on certain events by doing something like this`$("#warningMessage").show();` and it did not work. 
What do we have to do different in order to access this div tag. I suspect its behaving like this because it is under a script tag.

Here is the Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qwm4ewLa/3/).

Comment: Why is it in a script tag to begin with, don't do that. Also use display:none instead of visibility if you're going to use $.hide() and $.show().

Comment: are you doing the $("#warningMessage").show(); inside a $( document ).ready()? as @Mayank said, a fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: The markup under the `script` tag will never ever be accessible by the Jquery / JavaScript until it get attached to the DOM.

Comment: I need the script tag in order to use the kendo Popup Box @glubus

Comment: @BogdanGoie  there is a button click event where I am doing  $("#warningMessage").show();

Comment: @Mayank pls see the comments above.

Comment: @Mayank Is there a way to insert a div tag in script dynamically using jQuery ? Maybe I can do that if we cannot access div tag under script ?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ As per you comments, you want to access a `div` that is under `script tag` that you cannot until it get attached to the DOM. Given markup is a `Html template` used by kendo to generate a Markup. I need some of the javascript/Jquery code you used to initialize the markup to dig into the problem better ?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ and is the click event triggered? Try to debug by putting a debug point in the inspector of your browser inside the click event function OR add this inside the click event function : alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!"); and see if you get the alert.

Comment: @Mayank Here is sample jFiddle I put up. Would that help ? https://jsfiddle.net/qwm4ewLa/1/

Comment: @HereToLearn_ How you are initializing `notePopup` add that code the the fiddle as well.

Comment: @Mayank Here is the updated jsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/qwm4ewLa/3/

Comment: Looks like the .content() should generate the html, though from the looks of it it doesnt work. You're calling .content() on whatever is returned from kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow"). What is "kendowWindow" supposed to be? It looks like there's supposed to be a data-kendoWindow attribute somewhere, that doesnt exist. This would explain why the content() function does not work.

Comment: this could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505160/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-new-content-into-a-kendo-window

Answer (score 0):

Try running the kendo script first, then access the element by running the jQuery function you mentioned? I guess when the kendo script is finished, that template will be converted to valid html, and your div will be accesible for jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

It won't work because you first set a `visibility:hidden`.

So either you set it to `visible` when the event occurs, or you first `display:none` this `div` and make it `display:block` (using *show()*, *fadeIn()* and so on) for this specific event:

Here is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/liototo/jnmyswy4/1/

I set the warning div to:

```
#warningMessage{
  display: none;
}
```

The jQuery part is then as follow (just an example):

```
$('.add').on('click' , function(){

  if ($('.textNote').val())
        $('#warningMessage').show();
   else
    alert('enter something!');

});
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I need a way to access the div tag which is under script element.

Comment: OP clearly said he needs to put the div within a script tag, your code doesn't work in that scenario.